# What's the best language/platform for SOA on Linux in a post-Java world?

Tags: java, scala, programming-languages, mono, clojure

I need to choose a language/platform for the new development of a series of services in a SOA. I'm looking into Scala and Clojure but don't think the community and products are mature enough for a real-world enterprise product yet.

**Update/Clarifications:**

1. Of course we can use *many* languages/platforms for SOA but some language/platforms are easier and more suited for an SOA. IMO the *best* ones for SOA should allow interface programming (to ease definition of contracts), should have options for hosting the services (like Felix for Java or WCF in .NET) and scale well (see Twitter issues with RoR).
2. Java has always been the favourite in the enterprise market. However, many developers are looking into dynamic languages as well as talking about stagnation of Java after v6. As a result many new *post Java* languages have arrived: Scala, Clojure and Groovy to name a few that still run on JVM but are not Java.

I hope these clarify the question.

Comment: I can't find how to make this a community question since I think it belongs there.

Comment: You'll have to define "best" before you can get an answer.

Comment: how are Scala and Clojure 'post java'?

Comment: @Javier "post" means nothing more than "after", and both languages mentioned were clearly created after Java. Once you've got to grips with either of them, you'll also find that Java becomes a historic language in your world.

Comment: @Khash: +1 to your question but do you realize that even in 2030 we won't really be in a "post-Java" world?  There are just too many lines of Java in too many too big companies/institutions today and the rate at which they are growing is *fast*.  I'll probably be dead before this world becomes a 'post-Java' world :)

Comment: Since irony isn't welcome here, I'd better keep my opinion to myself. :) But I'm curious as to what the answer is.

Comment: By that definition, we're not even in a post-latin world; people still speak the language.  Java is pretty clearly starting to shrink, and the "10%" programmers are starting to look elsewhere for more productivity, more concurrency, and a better fit with agile.  We're in the world of post-java languages now...

Comment: Please don't base entire decisions on anecdotes about twitter.  see here for more details on the twitter ruby/scala situation: http://highscalability.com/scaling-twitter-making-twitter-10000-percent-faster  Twitter still serves all its web pages using ruby on rails.  They used scala for some backend work.  Are you planning on having as much traffic as Twitter?  If not, then you could probably use Rails.  If yes, then you could probably *still* use Rails :)  I like Scala better myself, but I get frustrated when I see anecdotes replacing analysis and research.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "mature enough for a real-world enterprise product", and your relative level of tolerance for living on the cutting edge.

For example, I'm currently building a "real-world enterprise product" in Clojure (I'd have been equally happy with Scala, it was only that Clojure fitted my needs slightly better from the concurrency and meta-programming perspective).

I'm very happy with my decision.

Some quick perspectives if you are considering this "post-Java" path:

- The communities are great and supportive, but you'll still have to solve problems yourself, if only because nobody else has run into the same problem yet. None of these are likely to be insurmountable, but it does present a bit of extra risk to delivery schedules.
- Both Scala and Clojure can be very productive (in terms of value delivered to customers per hour coding), but you can equally well write bad and unmaintainable code in any langauge. Java pretty much forces you to write things in a standardised, somewhat verbose but syntactically simple and understandable way. With Scala and Clojure you get a whole new arsenal of crazy ways to hit your target or shoot yourself in the foot. Is your team going to be able to make the best use of Scala/Clojure advantages?
- It's harder (though by no means impossible) to bring skilled people on board with existing Clojure/Scala skills. On the flipside, the people who do have these skills (or are keen to acquire them) are likely to be among the more talented / motivated developers so the search may still be productive.
- Be prepared to make tough decisions regarding whether to target language/library features that are "just round the corner". For example, do you wait for the enhanced primitive support coming in Clojure 1.3? Or make do with the perfectly adequate but slower boxed primitive functions in Clojure 1.2?
- A great benefit of being on the JVM is that you can still take full advantage of the Java ecosystem without being tied to Java as a language. Don't underestimate how useful this is: for example, I use a number of extremely well tested, mature Java libraries (e.g. [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty)) pretty much transparently in my Clojure application. This significantly reduces your risk and the amount of new development that you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment (having just completed a services/integration project ) Jersey on top of Spring are right up there on my favourites list for web services.

I can't offer any suggestions for a SOA framework, last time I was involved in that type of thing we user Oracle BPEL Process Manager and I have mixed feelings about it. We weren't using REST then either and I'm not sure how well the Oracle software works with it.

Answer (score 1):

For me python seems the easiest way to do some SOA and have interoperability with Windows computers. I don't have frameworks name but there is a lot of them in SOAP, REST, RPC...